# PHP - Creating .txt document in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, cookies

I am having trouble using `fopen()` to create a text document for later use as a cookie file.

I have read [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for this function, but to no avail.

**Notes:**

- Ubuntu
- read / writable ("w+")
- I have tried several storage locations including:

  - /home/jack/Desktop/cookie
  - /var/www/cookie
  - /home/jack/Documents/cookie

**PHP**

```
echo "debug";
echo "\r\n";

$cookie = fopen("/home/jack/Documents/cookie", "w+");
fclose($cookie);

if(!file_exists($cookie) || !is_writable($cookie))
{
    if(!file_exists($cookie))
    {
        echo 'Cookie file does not exist.';
    }
    if(!is_writable($cookie))
    {
        echo 'Cookie file is not writable.';
    }

    exit;
}
```

**Result**

- file is not created
- Output to browser: `debug Cookie file does not exist.Cookie file is not writable.`

**Other Fun Facts**

- I have tried using `fopen(realpath("/home/jack/Documents/cookie"), "w+")`
- `echo "\r\n"` gives a space. Why not a newline?

I believe the problem must be something to do with my permissions to create the file, but I have no problem "right-click" creating the text document on the Desktop.

**THIS WORKS** THIS WORKS **THIS WORKS** THIS WORKS **THIS WORKS** THIS WORKS **THIS WORKS**

```
echo "debug";
echo "\n";

$jack = "jack";
$cookie = "/home/jack/Documents/cookie";
touch($cookie);
chmod($cookie, 0760);

if(!file_exists($cookie) || !is_writable($cookie))
{
    if(!file_exists($cookie))
    {
        echo 'Cookie file does not exist.';
    }
    if(!is_writable($cookie))
    {
        echo 'Cookie file is not writable.';
    }

    exit;
}

fclose($cookie);
```

**THIS WORKS** THIS WORKS **THIS WORKS** THIS WORKS **THIS WORKS** THIS WORKS **THIS WORKS**

Instead of `fopen()`..

- `touch()` to create
- `chmod()` for permissions

I also added user name **jack** to **www-data** group.

- `chmod($path, 0760)` group read / write

**Reference**

- `chmod()` octal values [here](http://www.thetricky.net/php/chmod%20-%20octal%20values).

Comment: First step: [Turn on error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393).

Comment: Is your web server running as the same user you're logged in as when you're right clicking? (If so, you've probably done something Horribly Wrong).

Comment: 1) use `\n` for newlines on an Unix machine; 2) What permission/owner for the file?

Comment: Do you run this even through a webserver or just `php script.php` / shebang ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server is not executing as your user.  `touch /home/jack/Documents/cookie && chmod 777 /home/jack/Documents/cookie` to allow the web server user to access the file.

Note this is BAD in production environments.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation for [`file_exists`](http://www.php.net/file_exists) again. It does not take a file handle as an argument, it takes a string filename.  The same is true for [`is_writable`](http://php.net/is_writable).  Even if it did, you are opening the file handle and then immediately closing it, so I'm not sure why you're trying to use the file pointer at all after it's been closed.

You may be correct in that you have improper permissions set, but I would start here, first.

Also, if you're only trying to create the file, you may look into using the [`touch`](http://php.net/touch) method, instead:

```
if( touch( $filename ) ) {
    // It worked!
} else {
    // It didn't work...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a permission issue.  What user is PHP running as?  It's likely running as www-data or something similar.  You should make sure that the folders you are trying to write to are writable by either the user or group that PHP is running as.  If you created those folders while logged in a jack, they probably belong to jack:jack and are not accessible by www-data:www-data.

You can also add jack to the www-data group, to make things a bit easier for development.